# More than one delimiter for MultiAutoCompleteTextView?

Tags: android, tokenize

I am using a MultiAutoCompleteTextView which shows suggestions for user input. It only works when the items are separated by one or more spaces, but doesn't when a new line (i.e. button "enter" is pressed) is the delimiter.

The code so far (I think I got it from stackoverflow some time ago):

public class SpaceTokenizer implements Tokenizer {

```
@Override
public int findTokenStart(CharSequence text, int cursor) {
    int i = cursor; 
    while (i > 0 && text.charAt(i - 1) != ' ') {
        i--;
    }
    while (i < cursor && text.charAt(i) == ' ') {
        i++;
    }   
    return i;
}

@Override
public int findTokenEnd(CharSequence text, int cursor) {
    int i = cursor;
    int len = text.length();

    while (i < len) {
        if (text.charAt(i) == ' ') {
            return i;
        } else {
            i++;
        }
    }   
    return len;
}

@Override
public CharSequence terminateToken(CharSequence text) {
    int i = text.length();

    while (i > 0 && text.charAt(i - 1) == ' ') {
        i--;
    }   
    if (i > 0 && text.charAt(i - 1) == ' ') {
        return text;
    } else {
        if (text instanceof Spanned) {
            SpannableString sp = new SpannableString(text + " ");
            TextUtils.copySpansFrom((Spanned) text, 0, text.length(),
                    Object.class, sp, 0);
            return sp;
        } else {
            return text + " ";
        }
    }
}
```

}

I tried to implement something like "... || text.charAt(i) == '\n' ..." where I thought appropriate, but that didn't work.

So I would be very thankful for suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my question can be found here:
[Android and the CommaTokenizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5811336/android-and-the-commatokenizer)

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE!! stackoverflow.com/questions/12854336/autocompletetextview-backed-by-cursorloader