# Android and the CommaTokenizer

Tags: android, tokenize

I need a Tokenizer (for the AutoCompleteTextview) which can do the following:

1. Two words must be recognized as such when separated by a blank character
2. Two words must also be recognized as such when separated by a newline ("Enter" pressed)

1) is working, but how can I accomplish 2?

```
public class SpaceTokenizer implements Tokenizer {

@Override
public int findTokenStart(CharSequence text, int cursor) {
    int i = cursor; 
    while (i > 0 && (text.charAt(i - 1) != ' ')) {
        i--;
    }
    while (i < cursor && (text.charAt(i) == ' ' || text.charAt(i) == '\n')) {
        i++;
    }   
    return i;
}

@Override
public int findTokenEnd(CharSequence text, int cursor) {
    int i = cursor;
    int len = text.length();

    while (i < len) {
        if (text.charAt(i) == ' ' || text.charAt(i) == '\n') {
            return i;
        } else {
            i++;
        }
    }   
    return len;
}

@Override
public CharSequence terminateToken(CharSequence text) {
    int i = text.length();

    while (i > 0 && (text.charAt(i - 1) == ' ' || text.charAt(i - 1) == '\n')) {
        i--;
    }   
    if (i > 0 && (text.charAt(i - 1) == ' ' || text.charAt(i - 1) == '\n')) {
        return text;
    } else {
        if (text instanceof Spanned) {
            SpannableString sp = new SpannableString(text + " ");
            TextUtils.copySpansFrom((Spanned) text, 0, text.length(),
                    Object.class, sp, 0);
            return sp;
        } else {
            return text + " ";
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE!! stackoverflow.com/questions/12854336/autocompletetextview-backed-by-cursorloader

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to do this: `text.charAt(i) == ' ' || text.charAt(i) == '\n'` or `i-1` where appropriate.

Comment: I tried something like this, but it didn't work. What exactly do you mean by "or i-1"?

Comment: You have `text.charAt(i - 1)` in a few places - that's what the `i-1` is about.  Why doesn't it work?  It should find the space or the new line.

Comment: I edited my original entry and posted what I got so far; it only works partially, which means that there can be newlines, but before a newline there must be a blank space, otherwise it doesn't work.

Comment: You missed one near the top `while (i > 0 && (text.charAt(i - 1) != ' ')) {`

Comment: Yes, the line `while (i > 0 && (text.charAt(i - 1) != ' ')) {` should be `while (i > 0 && (text.charAt(i - 1) != ' ' && text.charAt(i-1) != '\n')) {`.  Please note that this uses && rather than ||.

Comment: Now it's working the way it should, thank you very, very much for your help! btw if you want, you could edit your comment into your last answer so that the answer is complete.

Comment: @deimos1988 if I'm reading this correctly, you never incorporated this last fix into your question's code snippet -- which would be even nicer (note that it's working now).

Answer (score 2):

Here is the whole code for anyone that is interested, had to implement this also in my own app. Thanks to [answer from @Haphazard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5811789/).

```
@Override
public int findTokenStart(CharSequence text, int cursor) {
    int i = cursor; 
    while (i > 0 && (text.charAt(i - 1) != ' ' && text.charAt(i - 1) != '\n')) {
        i--;
    }
    while (i < cursor && (text.charAt(i) == ' ' || text.charAt(i) == '\n')) {
        i++;
    }   
    return i;
}

@Override
public int findTokenEnd(CharSequence text, int cursor) {
    int i = cursor;
    int len = text.length();

    while (i < len) {
        if (text.charAt(i) == ' ' || text.charAt(i) == '\n') {
            return i;
        } else {
            i++;
        }
    }   
    return len;
}

@Override
public CharSequence terminateToken(CharSequence text) {
    int i = text.length();

    while (i > 0 && (text.charAt(i - 1) == ' ' || text.charAt(i - 1) == '\n')) {
        i--;
    }   
    if (i > 0 && (text.charAt(i - 1) == ' ' || text.charAt(i - 1) == '\n')) {
        return text;
    } else {
        if (text instanceof Spanned) {
            SpannableString sp = new SpannableString(text + " ");
            TextUtils.copySpansFrom((Spanned) text, 0, text.length(),
                    Object.class, sp, 0);
            return sp;
        } else {
            return text + " ";
        }
    }
}
```